# Can all keycode events be recognized by a user-script Jquery

Tags: jquery, userscripts

I am building a userscript with **Tampermonkey** that recognizes keycode events and when the key is fired it will do a function.

for eg. I want to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and its `keycode` is 13 so I used this code

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
var which = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
if(which == '13'){
    alert("You Pressed Enter key");
}
else if(which == '17'){
    alert("You Pressed Control key");
}
});
```

The code works fine with <kbd>Enter</kbd> and with <kbd>1</kbd> but doesn't work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> nor <kbd>Shift</kbd> and other keys.

Is there any thing I am missing or not all key events can be handled?

**NOTE :** I have been using [this link](http://keycode.info/) to get my keycodes and using them in my script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) isn't triggered for control key. Per the description on Mozilla docs:

> The `keypress` event is fired when a key that produces a character value is pressed down. Examples of keys that produce a character value are alphabetic, numeric, and punctuation keys. Examples of keys that don't produce a character value are modifier keys such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, or <kbd>Meta</kbd>.

One way to get around is to listen to `keydown` or `keyup` event:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  var which = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
  if (which == '13') {
    alert("You Pressed Enter key");
  } else if (which == '17') {
    alert("You Pressed Control key");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To determine left and right <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, and <kbd>shift</kbd> keys also :

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 16) {
          if (e.originalEvent.location == 1)
              alert('Left SHIFT pressed.');
          else
              alert('Right SHIFT pressed.');
      } else if (e.keyCode == 17) {
          if (e.originalEvent.location == 1)
              alert('Left CTRL pressed.');
          else
              alert('Right CTRL pressed.');
      } else if (e.keyCode == 18) {
          if (e.originalEvent.location == 1)
              alert('Left ALT pressed.');
          else
              alert('Right ALT pressed.');
          e.preventDefault();
      }
});
```

You have to include jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```