# Windows keycode events not recognized by a userscript

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, superscript

Why the windows keycode doesn't work in this superscript code (on edge chromium with Tampermonkey)?

```
(function () {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        //  67=C  91=windows key (or metaKey)    https://keycode.info/

        if (e.keyCode == 67 && e.keyCode == 91) {

            alert('detected')


        }
    }, false);
})();
```

I tried several letters with the windows key and using `e.metaKey` but without success.

---

ps: this not a duplicate of [Can all keycode events be recognized by a user-script Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51394664/can-all-keycode-events-be-recognized-by-a-user-script-jquery) because I don't use keypress

Comment: `Win` shortcuts are handled by OS so the browser doesn't even see them. You can use a separate utility like AutoHotKey, AutoIt, and so on.

Comment: Also note that `x == 67 && x == 91` is an impossible condition which will never be true. In general you need `e.metaKey && e.code == 'KeyC'`, use http://keycode.info/ for the actual values.

Comment: thanks a lot  I understand now that `x == 67 && x == 91 is an impossible condition`. But  if `the browser doesn't see [the win key]` why 1) https://keycode.info/ sees it? 2) why `e.metaKey` works (when used alone ― it doesn't work in combination with another letter) ?

Comment: 1) Only some `Win` keys are handled by OS, not all. 2) Depends on the letter.

Comment: if you copy past your comment in an answer, I will select it.

Comment: this answer backs up your point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6246851/1486850